# Ruby on Rails relation output between 2 models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I have two models.
The first is events and the second cities. in the events table i have an column which called city_id.
I want the city name on each event show view.

In the events controller:

```
@city = City.where(:id => @event.city_id)
```

And in the view:

```
<%= @city.name %>
```

A city has many events and a event belongs to a city.

The output in my view is just the word city.

Hm, Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code from:

```
@city = City.where(:id => @event.city_id)
```

to:

```
@city = @event.city
```

Besides being longer than necessary, the original code actually returns an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object - a lazy loaded query - for a collection of cities.  Calling `@city.name` was getting the class name for that relation - which is 'City'.  It would work properly if you added `.first` to trigger the query and get the first record:

```
@city = City.where(:id => @event.city_id).first
```

But as stated above, this is a lot more code than necessary ;).  Of course, this is assuming that you set up a `belongs_to :city` statement in your Event class.

Comment: `City.where(...)` returns a scope, formally known as `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It must be materialized into something with `.first` like you say.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was to easy to use it. I like it complicated ;)